# Python: threading: shouldn't a daemonized process return stdin/stdout to the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have what I thought was a straightforward thread setup: spawn a daemonized subthread, then wait for keyboard input to stop:

```
    MASTER = threading.Thread(target=QueueMonitor())
    MASTER.setDaemon(True)
    MASTER.start()

    while True:
        ZZ = raw_input("running...\ntype 'ZZ' to quit \n\n")
        if 'ZZ' in ZZ:
            print "1. cleaning up... (this can take some time)"
            KILLALL = 1
            sys.exit()
```

the subthread loops and prints output every 'x' seconds while waiting for the keyboard input to kill everything.
the code never returns to the 'ZZ' input but seems to stick on the subthread:

```
thread:  1
thread:  2
thread:  3
thread:  4
thread:  5
thread:  6
thread:  7
thread:  ...
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: target should be the name of the function only. When you say `target=QueueMonitor()`, the QueueMonitor function actually runs right then and there. Try `target=QueueMonitor` (without the '()') instead.

Comment: that was it.  I guess I can't checkmark a comment to mark it as the solution...

Comment: It's an answer now...

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `start()` instead of `run()`. The latter calls your thread func in the context of the *current* thread, not the new thread. As a result, your code never gets to the `while` loop.

Comment: good call on the edit - a vestige of an earlier cycle, but it's still not getting to the while loop - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Thread object using the 'target' parameter, the target should be a callable that will be run in the new thread after it is started. You called QueueMonitor() in the constructor, so it ran before the thread was created. Because your QueueMonitor runs forever, python never got to the point of creating Thread.

Just pass the name of the function instead:

```
MASTER = threading.Thread(target=QueueMonitor)
```